# Postgres combining two where clauses

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter, psql

i have a working query:

```
    "SELECT * FROM contract LEFT OUTER JOIN con_name on contract._id = con_name.contract WHERE $search_type ILIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY $sort_type ASC  ".
```

But i want to add another where clause like:

```
    WHERE(
  $times_type >= $from_date
  AND $times_type <=  $to_date)
```

How do i combine the two statements into one query please?

Comment: Side note: Learn to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the WHERE conditions with `AND`s if you want both of them valid at the same time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM contract LEFT OUTER JOIN con_name on contract._id = con_name.contract
WHERE $search_type ILIKE '%$search_word%' AND $times_type >= $from_date AND $times_type <=  $to_date ORDER BY $sort_type ASC
```

If one true is enough, you can use brackets and OR

```
SELECT *
FROM contract LEFT OUTER JOIN con_name on contract._id = con_name.contract
WHERE $search_type ILIKE '%$search_word%' OR ($times_type >= $from_date AND $times_type <=  $to_date) ORDER BY $sort_type ASC
```

Comment: Please i get the following error:
`   ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= integer LINE 1: ...act WHERE organisation ILIKE '%sds%' AND pub_date >= 2020-05... ^ HINT: Nooperator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`